# HTML video has controls, but doesn't load video or play

Tags: html, video

This is for a school assignment but I can't seem to get the video to work.

I'm using chrome. The buttons load and so does the player(black screen), but I can't get it to seem to work.

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
 <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
 <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
 <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
 <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
 <br/> 
 <video id="myVideo" width="420">
   <source src="audi.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div> 

<script> 
 var myVideo = document.getElementById("myVideo"); 

 function playPause() { 
  if (myVideo.paused) 
      myVideo.play(); 
  else 
    myVideo.pause(); 
 } 

 function makeBig() { 
   myVideo.width = 560; 
 } 

 function makeSmall() { 
    myVideo.width = 320; 
 } 

 function makeNormal() { 
   myVideo.width = 420; 
 } 
</script>
```

Comment: I jsfiddle will let people help you better.

Comment: I just ran this through locally with no issues. Are you sure that audi.mp4 exists? I'm using chrome and am *not* seeing the UI (the one that appears when you hover over the video) but the buttons work fine.